# How to make larger integers on MicroPython?

Tags: python, variables, integer, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm working on a personal project on Raspberry Pi Pico. I try to make mandelbrot set explorer on it. But I have a limit right now. On my searching, I see MicroPython stores integers only 32 bits but I need more than that. Is there any modules or technique to increase integer size?

If anyone has any advice, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Seems like there's some support for arbitrarily large integers built into MicroPython. Have you run a test case? See the message here: https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=4275#p24669

Comment: Yeah i saw that but i can't found it anywhere.

Comment: @SMD_Human I don't understand your reply. MicroPython supports arbitrarily large integers. Do you have some code that raises an error or doesn't behave as you expect?

Comment: @SMD_Human You can't find "it' anywhere because there is nothing to find. The poster of the comment the link points to just made a big number and froze it into the firmware. His example is illustrating that no matter what you do large numbers are supported right out of the box.